# Set macvim as default application after homebrew installation

Tags: homebrew, macvim

I've installed macvim via homebrew. This is working fine.

But when it commes to choose a default application for a new file type I cannot see MacVim. How can I set MacVim as the default application for a file type when it has been installed with homebrew?

**Note**: The question is not about how to select a default application in Finder, the question is how to set an application as default which is not listed in `/Applications` and there fore not shown by the Finder as a possible default application.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/why-cant-i-use-app-bundles-symlinked-into-applications-as-default-in-the-ope

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue. I moved MacVim.app to `/Applications` and then symlinked it into the Homebrew cellar directory.

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-65/MacVim.app /Applications/  
ln -s /Applications/MacVim.app /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-65/
```

Comment: Doesn't this need to be repeated each time MacVim is upgraded?

Comment: Worked for me. But mine was 7.3-66 which highlights @EricHu's concern... It suggests there is a better solution

Comment: I made easier without moving - only link: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-130/MacVim.app/ /Applications/MacVim.app` - but yes looks like link must be upgraded after changing the version of installed MacVim - because the path to the source folder will be changed.

Answer (score 12):

**Correction:** This is no longer the case, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/8699

Note that `brew linkapps` puts links in `~/Applications`, not `/Applications`. I had to follow the symlink (select your home directory from Favorites, select the `Applications` icon in the main pane, and click `Open`), then pull down the path list-box near the top of the dialog box (or hit Command+Up) to go one level back up the physical path.  Then you can see the icon for the actual `.app` folder.

Comment: It actually put the link in `/Applications` for me. The behavior must have changed.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the default app from Finder.

1. Select the file (e.g. foo.rb) and then choose 'Get Info' (command I, or File | Get Info).
2. Open the 'Open with' section.
3. Select your default app and then press 'Change All...'.

Comment: That's just an other way of getting the same problem. Since MacVim has been installed using homebrew it's never listed in the list of applications. This is also true if I choose to see the atlernative list of applications.

Answer (score 6):

Try running `brew linkapps`. That's how you're supposed to do it, but it never works for me; if the same is true for you, do `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app /Applications` (substituting the actual location of the app, if it differs on your system).

Homebrew should have told you that when you installed MacVim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. brew links did not help. I can see MacVim in the Launchpad and can open a file in finder now, but it's still not listed in the list of applications when I want it to set as the default application for .txt (or other file types).
Adding the link doesn't work either. MacVim does get listed now, but when I choose MacVim finder grays out the open button. Somme how it's not sufficient to just sym link the MacVim.app.

Comment: It works for me! The open button works too. My brew version is  0.9.5

Comment: `brew linkapps` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however I only wanted to use third-party ***MacPorts*** (a ***Homebrew*** alternative) applications ***where there was no native Apple version*** on the system.

To stop the ***MacPorts*** applications from being used in preference over native APPLE apps, I modified my $PATH: `vi ~/.profile`

```
# Original PATH which favoured MacPorts Commented-out
#export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

# Modified path prepending "/usr/bin" in front ensuring native apps favoured
export PATH="/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Using this PATH configuration, only if a native Apple application is not found will the ***MacPorts*** path be consulted.

**BEFORE** PATH Modified: Default VIM is ***MacPorts***

```
Terrences-MacBook-Pro:pi-ap terrence$ which vim
/opt/local/bin/vim
```

**AFTER** PATH Modified:  Default VIM is ***Apple's*** version

```
Terrences-MacBook-Pro:pi-ap terrence$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

If you want the third-party ***Homebrew*** apps to be default where there are alternatives in other paths, just ensure the ***Homebrew*** path is precedes them in your PATH.

Worked for my use-case, but might not be right for alternate use-cases.

Remember to logout after changing your ***.profile*** for the new PATH changes to be effective-