# How can I make a homebrew application the default for opening certain file types?

Tags: macos, finder, video, homebrew

I just installed mpv with homebrew on MacOS Catalina. Since I spend equal amounts of time using the terminal and Finder, I would like to open all video files with mpv from Finder. Unfortunately, I don't know how to locate the homebrew app when setting the default application for video files. To be clear, I'd like to open all my video files with mpv from Finder.

I have also tried the solution found in this thread: [Set macvim as default application after homebrew installation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/set-macvim-as-default-application-after-homebrew-installation)

But for mpv, there is no .app file. I tried moving and linking the /bin/mpv file but Finder wouldn't allow me to use that application as the default.

Comment: You may try making your own app. Copy any tiny app in a test directory. Right click > show package contents. Replace the binary in Contents/MacOS with the brew one. In the info.plist, replace `CFBundleTypeExtensions`'s array's string value with mpv. But this is not guaranteed to work. Remove any references to icon files or directories that don't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Read the FAQ @ https://mpv.io -> Reference -> [FAQ](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-make-mpv-the-default-application-for-opening-movie-files-on-macos-osx)**

---

## How can I make mpv the default application for opening movie files on macOS (OSX)?

- Install mpv as an app with Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask mpv
```

- If you need an alias in Applications/Launchpad, open a Finder window at /usr/local/Caskroom/mpv/your_mpv_version/. In there the mpv.app bundle has been generated. While holding Cmd+Alt, drag this .app into the Applications folder.
- Use duti to associate files with the application:

```
brew install duti
duti -s io.mpv avi all
duti -s io.mpv mkv all
duti -s io.mpv mp4 all
```

### Or you can do it macOS Finder

Find a video file you want to play in mpv and CMD + I to Get Info on it and then change the default app to be mpv and click Change All button. Rinse and repeat for other file types.

Comment: Awesome, what this did is that mpv actually showed up on the list of apps that could be linked to video files.

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to install something to make this possible or wanting to pop open a terminal window for every instance of mpv, I kept looking until I figured out a better method than James Brickley's.

- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>  → Automator
- In the Choose a type for your document: prompt, select "Application"
- In the search bar to the right of Actions and Variables type in 'script' and then select *Run Shell Script*
- Select your preferred shell from the *Shell:* dropdown (for simplicity's sake I'm choosing `/bin/bash`)
- Select "as arguments" from the *Pass input:* dropdown
- Delete the for loop that they pre-populated in the text area

Now you can just write your script as needed. I decided to set the PATH environment variable since I am using nix. So my entire "script" is:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.nix-profile/bin:$PATH"

mpv $@
```

Now, save your "Application" (I had to save it to `$HOME/Applications/mpv.app`), find a file that you want to set to be opened (eg. a `.mp4` file), select it, hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>, go down to *Open with:* and go to *Other...*, go to where you saved your "Application" (so `$HOME/Applications/` for me), select it, and hit "Add".

Finally, before you close the Info window, hit *Change All...* and that'll set it as the default.